# Print PDF with crop marks

Tags: pdf, printing, crop

I have an A4 PDF document that has **content all the way to the border** and I want to print it out.

Hence I print out on A3 sized paper (i.e. I print on paper twice the size) and then cut it to the actual size.

Is there an easy way to **add crop marks to the document when printing it**?

Answer (score 2):

If it’s a simple PDF document, you could possibly open it with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and then add crop marks with `Extensions > Render > Printing Marks…`. Or maybe [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/), with `Print… > Marks`.

Very hacky but might help somebody in a tight corner.

Comment: The menu has moved: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105873/how-do-i-get-printer-marks-in-inskscape-0-92
And then moved again under `Extensions > Document > Layout > Printing Marks`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro, this is easily done: File > Print > Advanced > Marks and Bleeds > Trim Marks

This may also be possible under Acrobat Reader, if someone would care to test it.

Comment: Thanks. And it is not available with the free Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way to do it on the **free** version. I was hoping there was, so that Sales would not have to come back to Prepress all the time to have us print out a proof with marks, but I'm not finding any way for them to do it in the free version (i.e. Acrobat Reader).

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, printed matter that extends to the paper's edge needs to go further than that! This is what is known as 'bleed'.

The page is normally printed on a larger sheet, with crop marks, and the colour objects extend **over** the cropped area, so that the trim line is **within** the inked area.

If the edge of an inked area is on the trim line, this invariably leaves a little white line where the blade and the ink don't quite meet. Cutting through the inked area guarantees no white lines.

To create a page with crop marks and bleed, of course, you need to go back to the original artwork in a competent application.